# one scale with multiple colors in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have dataframe like

```
dt = data.frame("a" =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), "b" =c(0,1,1,2,0,3,1))
```

I want to create a plot like (its a handmade so it has some errors, but the point is I want to bring all bubles on one line with color coded)

[image]

Though muy current code puts all the possible 4 values on x axis and show the dots on each scale

```
    p1<-ggplot(dt, aes(x = factor(a, levels = a), y = b, fill= b)) + 
  geom_point(stat='identity', size = 6, aes(col=b))  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.6,size = 25),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 25)) +
        coord_flip()
```

the above code produces following output

[image]

Comment: Something like `ggplot(dt, aes(x=1, y=a, color=as.factor(b))) + geom_point(size=4, shape=19)`, maybe?

Comment: Yes, Something like that, but I loose the labels on y axis and x axis shows multiple lables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your output example, you just need to use the same `x` (for example `x=1`), 
and remove the labels:

```
dat = data.frame("a" =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), "b" =c(0,1,1,2,0,3,1))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=1, y=a, color=as.factor(b))) + # b will control the color groups
  geom_point(size=6, shape=19) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(min(dat$a), max(dat$a), by = 1)) + # in order to print each y labels
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), # element_blank() removes the element
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), # title refers to the title of axis
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") # this removes the legend
```

[image]

Use `scale_y_reverse()` if you want to reverse the order of y axis:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=1, y=a, color=as.factor(b))) + 
  geom_point(size=6, shape=19) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=seq(min(dat$a), max(dat$a), by = 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Use `aspect.ratio` if you want to narrow it down:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=1, y=a, color=as.factor(b))) + 
  geom_point(size=6, shape=19) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=seq(min(dat$a), max(dat$a), by = 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        aspect.ratio = 3)
```

[image]

---

You can "cluster" them together using `reorder()` for the `y` values, based on `b` (notice that you'll lose the `y` axis natural ordering):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=1, y=reorder(a, b), color=as.factor(b))) + 
  geom_point(size=6, shape=19) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        aspect.ratio = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to cluster them together, Like it should show all the 0s first, then 1, 2 and 3 ?

Comment: That won't make them ordered by `y` values anymore though. You will have 7 before 4 for example. So I'm not sure where you're going with this.

Comment: In that case the order of the y values would also be changed accordingly. So, idea was to see which y values clustered together with 0s, then 1s and so on..